# How to turn off color and remove the time in Git log?

Tags: git

As mentioned in the title, how to turn off color and remove the time?

Because I need to copy the output to `pbcopy`,
but the color mode will make the output contain special characters.

[image]

Comment: `git help config`, specifically look for `color.ui`.

Comment: What time do you want to remove? From the `git log`? Please be clear.

Answer (score 27):

I’ve added the following to the `~/.gitconfig` file, in order to remove most of the color:

```
[color]        
    ui = false
    branch = false
    diff = false
    interactive = false
    status = false
    log = false
```

(Note: I’m running `git-bash` from MINGW64 on Windows 10.)

Comment: to render prompt un-colored ,add this line to .bash_profile :                                           export PS1='[\u@\h \w]\$'

Comment: to keep the ls command color-free, i added the following alias to .bash_profile : alias d='ls -al --color=never'

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine for me (on Linux). I also noticed that the only thing required to remove colors was this


`
[color] 
    ui = false
`

Comment: Indeed, it seems that `ui = false` (or `ui = no` or `ui = never`) alone is sufficient to disable all coloring. You only need the other settings if you want to _selectively opt back in_ to coloring.

Comment: Adding a link to the [Colors in Git](https://git-scm.com/book/sv/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_colors_in_git) section in the Git Book.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't want to disable colors for *all* commands, you can at least disable it just for the current log command:

```
git log --stat --no-color
```

Regarding the time, what you see is not the usual log output. Check if you have defined any alias for [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Note: as mentioned in "[Copy Shell Output via the Command Line](http://davidwalsh.name/copy-shell-output-command-line)", **an easy way to copy to pbcopy is to pipe to it**:

> pbcopy and clip.  Using pbcopy within the shell, the output of an execution can automatically be added to the copy queue (or clipboard).
>   Piping pbcopy at the end of the command makes this magic possible.

```
git log --stat --no-color | pbcopy
```

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss are you addressing this question to the OP? If yes, you should comment under the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get `--no-color` to work. It's probably a windows thing.

This worked for me to remove colors from git output on windows:

```
git status | findstr .
```

Comment: Same here on linux. Used `git ... | less`