# Prevent Powershell output in white color

Tags: powershell

I have set my powershell in desert-style color. As a result, any text printed with white or yellow color is not visible. Is there any way to centrally override any output on host with these colors to black?

[image]

P.S. I am not searching on how to prevent git from printing in white. There are other programs that do it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call an *external program* such as `git` from PowerShell and you neither capture nor redirect its output, it prints directly to the console / terminal.

This implies that PowerShell has no control over how that output renders.

(For *PowerShell commands*, you get *limited* control over what colors are used based on the *meaning* of output, via `$host.PrivateData`, which has properties such as `WarningForegroundColor` and `WarningBackgroundColor`, for instance.)

**Solution options**:

- Preferably - *if the terminal application supports it* - redefine the color named "white" as needed to provide sufficient contrast.

  - For instance, Windows Terminal on Windows and iTerm.app on macOS support this...
  - ... while regular console windows (`conhost.exe`) on Windows  do *not*.
- Otherwise, there is no general, program-agnostic solution, and the next best thing is to *disable* coloring.

  - I know you don't want *per-external-program* workarounds, but just to note one for `git`: use `--no-color` in individual `git` calls or disable coloring via `git`'s configuration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545443/45375).
  - *Some* external programs respect the presence of a `NO_COLOR` environment variable as a signal to disable coloring; others may respond to a `TERM` environment-variable value of `xtermm` or `xterm-mono` - neither approach works with `git`, however.
  - However, *most* external programs that support colored output usually apply coloring *conditionally*: That is, they only use coloring when their stdout (standard output) stream is connected to a *terminal*, and not when redirecting to a file or when the output is sent through a *pipeline*.
  - This enables the following **workarounds** - which still must be applied on a *per-call basis*, however:

    ```bash
     # Enclosure in (...) involves capturing the output by PowerShell,
     # which disables coloring.
     # Note: Captures all output up front before relaying it.
     (git log)

     # Streaming alternative.
     git log | Write-Output

     # To preserve `git log`'s interactive paging:
     git log | more
    ```